# Python - Check to see if an application is a web browser

Tags: python-3.x

I'm building a program which connects python to a gui built in html. It's built to accept the path to a browser application as a parameter. Once checking to make sure that that application exists, I'd love to do a validation check to make sure that the application is in fact a web browser. Is there any way to do this?

Apologies for the lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, don't ask people to input the path to their browser. The OS already knows what is their browser of choice, it's called the default browser, and it's at least more convenient.  No approach is really hack-free anyway.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get().open('https://www.example.com')
```